# Spotfire Appending Rows into Information Link

Tags: spotfire, tibco

Hi I'm looking to append rows from an excel sheet into an information link prior to the data being pulled into spotfire, is this possible? The data being loaded from information link is on-demand so I'm hoping to get a dynamic data table that pulls only on-demand data rows from both the information link and the other excel sheet(both having similar structure).

Thanks!

Comment: Create a join information designer on your secondary excel.

Comment: Does this mean the excel data needs to be loaded into the server as a data source in order for it to be available in the information designer?